# How to verify website users using smartphone fingerprint authentication or face recognition?

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint, two-factor-authentication, android-fingerprint-api

I want to provide an alternative login to a website using fingerprint or facial recognition for mobile users (preferably android). Is this possible? If yes, what are the steps?

Most of the information I found deals with mobile apps- even those have security restrictions. I am a bit confused as to the approach.
Initially I thought I could store fingerprint data in a database of some sort and match with the fingerprint data provided by the android device, just like password authentication. With further research I found that this is not allowed due to security reasons.

Does Google provide some form of authentication similar to this?
I am *new* to building android apps, but I will appreciate your help even if it involves building a mobile app of some sort just for that particular website (as a last resort).
In particular I would like to know how to verify the user on the server side? Assuming I receive a response of some sort from the phone, for example:

```
PhoneUser={verified: true, ...}
```

If only I can transmit/store a key(generated during registration) that will be unique to a user's biometric data. Then I could match that with the response from the phone to verify the user. I have heard a little about cryptoobjects would it be a good solution?
How do I verify that the fingerprint match belonged to a user on my web application?
Do I track the device to make sure it belongs to the user (IMEI) or is this just too big for a simple website?

Comment: The way Android's biometric API is meant to be used is: you ask it to initiate a biometric authentication, and it eventually answers with a callback saying whether the autentication succeeded (i.e. the fingerprint/face/whatever matched any of those enrolled on the device) or failed. Optionally you can also ask to have a `CryptoObject` unlocked by the authentication, which will make a previously generated key available for performing some cryptographic operation if the authentication succeeded.

Comment: Can a crypto object be stored in a database or generate a key to verify a user?

Comment: Note that you can't really tie an authentication to a specific fingerprint or a specific user. All you really can tell is whether the fingerprint/face/whatever presented by the user matched any of those that have been enrolled on the device. As for the database part, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. You can create a fingerprint-protected keypair on the device and send the public key to your server. When the server wants proof that the user has authenticated something, it sends some random data to the app. The app asks the user to do a biometric authentication.

Comment: (continued) which temporarily unlocks the private key from the keypair and allows you to sign the data you received from the server. The server can then use the corresponding public key to verify the signature.

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising. Are there any links or docs that can guide me on how to create the 'fingerprint-protected keypair'?